# Unable to find the mojo 'generate-sources'

Tags: maven, playn

When I try to install playn, I get that :

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building PlayN Tests Android
[INFO]    task-segment: [install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [enforcer:enforce {execution: enforce-maven}]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.1.1:generate-sources': Unable to find the mojo 'generate-sources' (or one of its required components) in the plugin 'com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin'
Component descriptor cannot be found in the component repository: org.sonatype.aether.RepositorySystem.
```

Comment: That looks like an output of a Maven 2.? Cause i don't see any pom snippet you should try to build with Maven 3..

Comment: That is correct, that was my mistake, I had a PATH issue and maven2 was used instead of maven 3

Answer (score 3):

The error is caused by using Maven 2 when you need to be using Maven 3.